# 301 redirect doesnot work in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect from `https://*****.com/lp/index.html`
to `https://*****.com/lp/`

so I put these two line in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /lp/index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^/lp/index\.html$ /lp/ [R=301,L]
```

and now the whole redirect block in my htaccess file is like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /lp/index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^/lp/index\.html$ /lp/ [R=301,L]
```

but the index.html redirect not working.

Does anyone know why? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

# remove /lp/index.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+lp/index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /lp/ [L,R=301,NE]
```

Clear your browser cache and retest.

Comment: Thank you ,I changed my code to the code below `# remove /lp/index.html
` , it worked.   But my code (the first three lines ,  I mean the index.php remove code) worked well , so I write the almost same one for removing index.html ,it failed. I don't know why...

Comment: Your rule didn't work because `RewriteRule ^/lp/index\.html$ ` has a leading slash before `lp` which is not available in htaccess. So it must be: `RewriteRule ^lp/index\.html$  ...`

Answer (score 0):

try this 
http://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/redirect-generator.htm 
with Apache .htaccess redirect option